Leaflet map in projected coordinate system
Is there a way to show the leaflet map in a custom projected coordinated system, such as the North America Albers Equal Area Conic_1? We can do this in D3.js, but can we do it in Leaflet.js?
Something like this image.


Yes, it's possible, see https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html

Do you think it's a projected coordinated system or geographic? Here is an example of a projected coordinate system in ArcGIS.
North America Albers Equal Area Conic_1

About which one are you asking: your image or example quoted in my comment?

See a list of main projections with images: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections

Yes, this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection
Albers Conic
Equal-area
Heinrich C. Albers
Two standard parallels with low distortion between them.

Yes, it's possible. It's EPSG:42303 (see https://epsg.io/42303).

Thanks! Does this need to be added to my script file? or do I need to edit the coordinate system in the Leaflet.js file?

You will need Proj4Leaflet plugin, see https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet

Awesome, I will give this one a try.

I was not aware there was a plugin for projection. Here is what I did to change the WGS 84 projection to Albers Equal Area Conic (42303) projection.
     var crs42303 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:42303',
        '+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
         +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs', {
         resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 
         2, 1],
        origin: [0, 0]
    });


    var map = L.map('map', {
      crs: crs42303,
      maxZoom: 14,
      minZoom: 0,
    }).setView([40, -97.0], 1);

And here is a screenshot of my map. I haven't use Tile, because I had a GeoJSON file.

